# ArraySort not displaying?

Tags: java

It is not giving any output but the code runs without error.I wanted to show all the methods including the result for bubble sort, selection sort and compare sort? How do I call the methods. When I run it, it is not giving me any output. So, I just needed help to run the code.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = new int[100];
    int[] B = new int[100];
  }
//get a random number;

  private int getRand() {
    Random in = new Random();
    return in.nextInt(100);
  }
//fill an array with numbers from 0 to 99;

  public static void fillArray(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      array[i] = i;
    }
  }
//copy an array to another;

  public static void copyArray(int[] aArray, int[] bArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
      bArray[i] = aArray[i];
    }
  }
//swap two numbers in an array according to index;

  private void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
//random select two numbers in an array and switch them;

  int disorderArray(int[] array) {
    int i, j;
    i = getRand();
    j = getRand();
    swap(array, i, j);
    //System.out.println("the index of the 2 swapped numbers are " + i +  " " +     
    j
    );
    return i;
  }

//print out the array;
public static void printArray(int[] array, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - col + 1; i += col) {
        for (int j = i; j < i + col; j++)
            System.out.print("number " + j + " is " + array[j] + ";  ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = array.length - array.length % col; i < array.length; i++)
        System.out.print("number " + i + " is " + array[i] + ";  ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}

//bubble sort;
public void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
                swap(array, j, j + 1);
        }
    }
}

//selection sort;
public void selectionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        int p = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)
            if (array[p] > array[j])
                p = j;
        if (i != p)
            swap(array, i, p);
    }
}

//compare two arrays;
public static boolean compareArrays(int[] aArray, int[] bArray) {
    boolean s = true;
    int i = 0;
    if (aArray.length == bArray.length) {
        while (s && i < aArray.length) {
            if (aArray[i] != bArray[i])
                s = false;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

}

Comment: You're not showing us all your code. The code you've posted only allocates two empty arrays when run - none of methods are ever called and you're not trying to output anything anywhere.

Comment: I dont know how do I do that? I do not understand how do i do it? I just this codes.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I have edited it. But I dont know how to call the methods and especially array sorts bubble, selection and compare arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented some methods, but you need to invoke them from your `main` method, e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] A = new int[100];
  int[] B = new int[100];

  fillArray(A);
  // more method calls...
}
```

Note, you have implemented both class (`static`) methods and instance (non-static) methods. The semantics for how you call them differs. If your program is is implemented in a class named `Foo`, you can write the following:

```
// method call to class method
Foo.fillArray();

// method call to instance metod requires an instance
Foo fooInstance = new Foo();
int randomNumber = fooInstance.getRand();
```

Normally, you use instance methods to manipulate instance variables and class methods to manipulate class variables or more commonly as helper methods that do not involve state at all. More information regarding this can be found in the [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) chapter of Oracle's Java Tutorial (scroll down to Class Methods).